# How to use safe threading for a timer(Change timer properties from different thread)

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, timer

To access a memo on my form,I use the following code

```
    public string TextValue
    {
        set
        {
            if (this.Memo.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    this.Memo.Text += value + "\n";
                });
            }
            else
            {
                this.Memo.Text += value + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd like to use the same code to enable/disable my timer,but there's no property InvokeRequired for a timer.

```
    public int Timer
    {
        set
        {
            if (this.timer.InvokeRequired) //?? No such thing
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    if (value == 1)
                        this.timer.Enabled = true;
                    else
                        this.timer.Enabled = false;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                if (value == 1)
                    this.timer.Enabled = true;
                else
                    this.timer.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

How to enable the timer from a different thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "this" a form object?

Assuming you created the Timer object using the form designer the object is created by the same thread as the one that created the form so checking the form's InvokeRequired property effectively tells you the same thing.

Comment: Yes,"this" is a form object,but I'm calling that function from a different thread inside a critical section.

Comment: That's fine. All the InvokeRequired boolean tells you is if the CurrentThread == ThreadThatCreatedTheObject. The thread that created the form is the same thread that created the timer so this will work.

Comment: No,it doesn't.I can't enable the timer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the timer from the code like below:

```
public int Timer
{
    set
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired) 
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                if (value == 1)
                    this.timer.Enabled = true;
                else
                    this.timer.Enabled = false;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            if (value == 1)
                this.timer.Enabled = true;
            else
                this.timer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```