# I am trying to use the AdvancedColorInfo class, but can't work out how to instantiate it

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

```
private AdvancedColorInfo advancedColorInfo = new AdvancedColorInfo();
```

I have tried the above code, but get this error:

> “AdvancedColorInfo doesn't contain a constructor that takes 0
>   arguments.”

I am trying to use the method `IsHdrMetadataFormatCurrentlySupported`, so I need to create an instance of the `AdvancedColorInfo` class.

I tried changing the UWP Windows version that is mentioned in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.advancedcolorinfo) but no luck.

How do I get an instance of `AdvancedColorInfo`?

Comment: Are you calling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.getadvancedcolorinfo ?

Comment: i am calling this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.advancedcolorinfo

Comment: I am not getting any constructor signature suggestion.

Comment: Press F12 on it and look at the metadata

Comment: No constructor is there in class definition. Only methods and props are there

Comment: There's a clue! The constructor may be private. Therefore to construct an instance of it there could be a static method, e.g. `AdvancedColorInfo.Create()` or it could be derived from another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an `AdvancedColorInfo` you don't `new` them up [directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713536/instantiate-net-class-without-public-constructor).

Instead, you need to:

```
var displayInfo = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
var colorInfo = displayInfo.GetAdvancedColorInfo();
var isHDRSupported = colorInfo.IsHdrMetadataFormatCurrentlySupported(yourFormatPassInHere);
```

The first method call is a `static` call to get the `DisplayInformation`. The second is to get the `AdvancedColorInfo` from the `DisplayInformation`.